# Error creating bean with name 'messageConverters' defined in class path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Despues de un buen rato regreso a `JAVA` pero no funciona, estoy configurandolo con `SWAGGER` pero incluso sin esto no funciona.

Es apenas el `spring initializer` pero no funciona, ni siquiera arranca

**Controlador**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class Vistas {

    @GetMapping(path = "/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello";
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/hello-name")
    public String helloWithParam(@RequestParam String name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Error**

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters.configurePartConverters(HttpMessageConverters.java:140)

The following method did not exist:

    org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.getPartConverters()Ljava/util/List;

The method's class, org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/meyam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.2.9.RELEASE/spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/http/converter/support/AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter: file:/C:/Users/meyam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.2.9.RELEASE/spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar
    org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter: file:/C:/Users/meyam/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.2.9.RELEASE/spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter

Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:982)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:929)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:457)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  3.513 s
Finished at: 2021-01-28T11:38:10-05:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) on project demo: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 0):

veo que estas un poco confundido con respecto a spring-boot y conceptos de maven, parece que el proyecto lo creaste en la web https://start.spring.io/ pero solo lo generaste sin dependencias, te explico lo que causa el error:

Primero la librería:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

Esta librería es necesaria únicamente si necesitas un proyecto spring-boot básico con las funcionalidades de spring-core que seria la inyección de dependencia, logging y test, pero nada de funcionalidad web y sin servidor tomcat.

Cuando agregas la librería `spring-web` al parecer se genera un conflicto con la autoconfiguración de spring-boot-starter.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Para solucionar el problema elimina las dependencias `spring-web` y `spring-boot-starter` y sustitúyelas por la siguiente dependencia:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Aun que mezclar las dependencias de `spring-boot-starter` y `spring-boot-starter-web` no genera problemas se sustituye porque es redundante ya que `spring-boot-starter-web` incluye todo lo de `spring-boot-starter`, también ten encuentra que estas librerías no se les coloca la `version` porque la heredan del `POM padre spring-boot-starter-parent` al final tu pon quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: El error sigue siendo el mismo, incluso si despliego via tomcat o jetty

Comment: Es extraño que continúes con el error, según mis pruebas con el `POM` corregido como te lo muestro al final no deberías tener el error segun el IDE que utilices dile que actualice las dependencias del `POM` o ejecútalo en línea de comando para validar.

Comment: Continua el Error, actualizé POM, borre build, reinicié todo, incluso las lib.. los actualizé las últumas versiones y nada, todo el rato es el mismo error

Comment: @user75463 prueba ejecutar los siguientes comandos en la raíz del proyecto `mvnw clean package -DskipTests` y después `mvnw spring-boot:run` esto limpiara el proyecto y después corremos el proyecto, si esto falla te recomendaría que muestres la estructura del proyecto he indiques que IDE estas utilizando.